# Is there a list gui component in Java 8 Swing?

Tags: java, swing, listview

I would like each element of the list to have multiple components. Maybe a title, some text below it or even a button? Is that possible? I'm hoping to find something similar to SwiftUI's list view.

Something like this: https://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image-8-1024x607.png (not enough reputation to add images)

Comment: You wont find a list component that has "a button below". Any UI component system will rather give you ways combine various components. In Java, you just use a panel, and place a list inside, and put a button on the same panel for example. Honestly: have you done any prior research on swing, like read the oracle tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@ewramner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63597790/6579265) is correct. A custom `ListCellRenderer` will get it done. Here is an example using a `JPanel` as the renderering component which includes a nested `JPanel` (named `rightPanel`).

(Some comments inside code)

```
public class MultiComponentListCellRenderer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person mike = new Person("Mike", 25);
        Person alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
        DefaultListModel<Person> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        model.addElement(mike);
        model.addElement(alice);
        JList<Person> personJList = new JList<>(model);
        personJList.setCellRenderer(new PersonListCellRenderer());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, personJList);
    }

    public static class Person {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    public static class PersonListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Person> {
        private JLabel nameLabel;
        private JLabel ageLabel;
        private JLabel iconLabel;
        private JPanel rightPanel;

        public PersonListCellRenderer() {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            nameLabel = new JLabel();
            ageLabel = new JLabel();
            iconLabel = new JLabel();
            try {
                Image personImg = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/people-80/96/Picture1-512.png"));
                ImageIcon personIcon = new ImageIcon(personImg.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                iconLabel.setIcon(personIcon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            add(iconLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

            //Right panel will contain name and age, top and bottom respectively 
            rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            rightPanel.add(nameLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            rightPanel.add(ageLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setOpaque(true); //for visible backgrounds
            rightPanel.setOpaque(true);//for visible backgrounds
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Person> list, Person value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            nameLabel.setText(value.name);
            ageLabel.setText(String.valueOf(value.age));
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
                rightPanel.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                rightPanel.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
                rightPanel.setBackground(list.getBackground());
                rightPanel.setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            return this;
        }

    }
}
```

The result:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1):

It is not very detailed, but the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) mentions that you can use a custom [ListCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html). That should do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try `NetBeans` and it's GUI builder?

[image]

On the right panel you have a `Palette` that gives you pretty good overview of components available in `Swing`.

As for the `List` itself, you are probably looking at something like this: [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I am already using Eclipse and Windowsbuilder. I don't like Eclipse, but I would rather not spend time learning to use another IDE.